# Why wouldn't a prototype function be able to read a prototype property?

Tags: javascript, function, prototype

I have this code, that returns an Uncaught ReferenceError: year is not defined.

```
function Car(color, drivetrain) {
    this.color = color;
  this.drivetrain = drivetrain;
  this.stats = function(){
  console.log(color + " " + drivetrain);
  };
}

Car.prototype.year = 2012;
Car.prototype.funcyear = function () { console.log(year);}; //reference error

var toyota = new Car('red', 'fwd');
toyota.stats();
console.log(toyota.year);
toyota.funcyear();
```

Why wouldn't this be able to work, shouldn't the `funcyear` function be located in the prototype, so year should be accessible?

Comment: `year` property should be accessed within a method through [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_this_for_object_references) context

Comment: why is the `this` necessary?

Comment: _why is the this necessary?_ Follow the link

Comment: Properties don't automatically become local variables within methods. You have to still access them from the current object – `this.year`.

Comment: `this` refers to owner of the method which is being called...`year` is the property of the owner `Car` hence it should be access using `this` context..

Comment: Thanks guys, that was easy, and helpful.!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because only `year` would reference a variable (or a function), but not a property.
To reference a property you have to name the object, this property is attached to.

```
Car.prototype.funcyear = function() {
    console.log(this.year);
};
```

**Note:**

```
function Car(color, drivetrain) {
    this.color = color;
    this.drivetrain = drivetrain;
    this.stats = function(){
        //this part is "dangerous", because color and drivetrain reference the local variables 
        //in this surrouunding function-call, NOT the properties of this instance
        //so you might change the properties, but you don't see any effect.
        console.log(color + " " + drivetrain);
    };
}
```